# Generating the output file name from the input file in bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
convert "$1" -resize 50% "$2"
```

Instead of passing two arguments while the script is run I want to mention just the source (or input file name) and the output file name should be auto-genarated from the source file name. Something like this `"$1" | cut -d'.' -f1".jpg"`. If the input file name was `myimage.png`, the output name should be `myimage.jpg`. `.jpg` should be appended to the fist part of the source file name. It should also work if the argument is: `*.png`. So how can I modify my script?

Comment: Does this work at the comand line: `convert "*.png" -resize 50% "*.jpg"` ?? I suspect you'll need a loop in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expansion `${X%pattern}` removes `pattern` of the end of $X.

```
convert "$1" -resize 50% "${1%.*}.jpg"
```

To work on multiple files:

```
for filename ; do
    convert "$filename" -resize 50% "${filename%.*}.jpg"
done
```

This will iterate over each of the command line arguments and is shorthand for `for filename in "$@"`. You do not need to worry about checking whether the argument is `*.png` - the shell will expand that for you - you will simple receive the expanded list of filenames.

Answer (score 2):

```
convert "$1" -resize 50% "${1%.*}.jpg"
```

The magic is in the `%.*` part, which removes everything **after the last dot**. If your file is missing an extension, it will still work (as long as you don't have a dot anywhere else in the path).

Answer (score 0):

```
OUTFILE=`echo $1|sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`.jpg
convert "$1" -resize 50% "$OUTFILE"
```

Comment: consider using `$()` instead of backticks